# Update ipAllowList in mysql shell

Tags: mysql, mysql-innodb-cluster, mysql-shell

I haven't found the way to update `ipAllowlist` in innodbcluster using mysql shell. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you should be able to do this using `Cluster.setOption()` or `Cluster.setInstanceOption()`.

Comment: Depending on whether you want to update the entire cluster or just one instance.

Comment: Thank you but those options don't support ipAllowList.

Comment: Then I suspect you can only set it when you're creating the instance, not dynamically.